# Why does the limit of the average of $L^\infty(\Omega\times(0,T))$ function over $\Omega\times [t,t+\epsilon]$ when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ exist?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, partial-differential-equations

In these lecture notes on PDEs

http://www.sbai.uniroma1.it/pubblicazioni/doc/phd_quaderni/02-1-and.pdf (p. 26, sec 4.1)

it is claimed that
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} \int\limits_{t-\epsilon}^t \int\limits_\Omega v(x,\tau) \varphi(x,\tau)\, dx \, d\tau = \int\limits_\Omega v(x,t) \varphi(x,t)\, dx  $$
for almost all $t\in (0,T)$. Here $\varphi \in W_{2,1}^2(Q_T)$, $v\in L^\infty(Q_T)$, $Q_T= \Omega \times (0,T)$ and $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I struggle to see why this limit exists for almost all $t$. I would see it if the function $\tau \mapsto \int\limits_\Omega v(x,\tau) \varphi(x,\tau)\, dx$ were continous, but I don't see why this is the case, without requiring more regularity for $v$. If the claim is in general not correct, I would be curious about which further assumptions would guarantee the existence of the limit.

Comment: Looks like Lebesgue differentiation theorem ?

Comment: Yes I think you are correct. The function $g(\tau):=\int_\Omega v(x,\tau) \varphi(x,\tau) dx $ should be in $L_1([0,T])$ due to Fubinis theorem. By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem the integral $\int_{t-\epsilon}^t g(\tau) d\tau$ converges to $g(t)$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ for a.e. t. Thank you @daw  . If you like, post this comment an answer so I can accept it.